# Кроссбраузерное добавление и удаление события

Tags: javascript

Нужен четкий и понятный код, который бы добавлял и удалял события.

Выглядеть код должен так:

```
var kod={
    go:{
        add:function(elem, type, handler) {

        },
        remove:function(elem, type, handler) {

        }
    }
}
```

Кто сможет такой написать?

Простой быдло код из интернета не предлагать.

Код должен позволять додобавлять события, удалять их и работать они в том порядке в каком были добавлены.
А при добавлении одного и того же события, повторное добавление игнорируется.

Comment: А что значит быдлокод для вас? Тут можно дать решение, а вы уже делаете его красиво, как надо вам.

Comment: [Антон Мухин](http://hashcode.ru/users/293/антон-мухин), беглый взгляд на ник и рейтинг ответит на первый ваш вопрос. =) Удалить его, что ли, за то, что не юзает поиск?

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна идея:

Для всех функций, которые должны исполняться, сделать один интерфейс, например, у всех должен быть метод `exec`. Создать одну общую для всех событий функцию, которая должна будет исполнять все эти интерфейсы. Вот как-то так:

```
//Общая ф-я
genFunc = function() {
    this.masHandlers;
    this.add(handler){
        //Добавляется новый хэндлер к массиву this.masHandlers
    }
    this.del(handler) {
        //Удаляется
    }
    //Функция исполнения
    this.go() {
        for(... ...)
        handler[i].exec();
    }
}
```

В то время как каждый `handler[i]` - разные функции, но они все имеют метод `exec()`.
А уж как добавлять и удалять элементы из массива - дело техники.

```
add:function(elem, type, handler) {
    //Добавляем:
    elem[type]// как-нибудь извлечь функцию и применить к ней .add() метод
    // не забыть про проверку на первый вызов. Т.е. если не установлено никакой 
    // функции для события type
}
```

PS:
Так как вы не *быдлокодер*, то уж точно знаете, как выполнять операции, которых я тут не привел (которые закомментированы словестно). Или их можно легко найти в гугле.

*UPDATE1*:
Ах **нет**, надо элементу для события установить одну функцию, например

```
elem.onclick = function() {
    genFunc.go();// обращаемся к глобальной переменной
}
```

а в методе

```
add:function(elem, type, handler) {
    genFunc.add(handler, type);// обращаемся к глобальной переменной
}//...
```

Вот как-то так. Может, такие наброски могут быть полезны.